# Calculation of TOLUD - Can't understand Intel's programming example

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, bios, uefi

Modern Intel x86-64 processors contain a register TOLUD (Top of Low Usable DRAM), which effectively marks the boundary in 32-bit address space between RAM and I/O. To a first approximation, writes from the cores to addresses below this value go to RAM and writes to addresses above this value go to PCI address space. There are a few wrinkles on top of this, mostly related to the various memory holes and remappings that occur when using the x86-64 architecture.

Intel documentation gives an example for calculating a TOLUD value (see, e.g., [12th-generation-core-processor-datasheet](https://edc.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/publications/12th-generation-core-processor-datasheet-volume-2-of-2/top-of-low-usable-dram-tolud-0-0-0-pci-offset-bc/) at time of writing):

> C1DRB3 is set to 4GB
>
> TSEG is enabled and TSEG size is set to 1MB
>
> Internal Graphics is enabled, and Graphics Mode Select is set to 32MB
>
> GTT Graphics Stolen Memory Size set to 2MB
>
> BIOS knows the OS requires 1G of PCI space.
>
> BIOS also knows the range from 0_​FEC0_​0000h to 0_​FFFF_​FFFFh is not usable by the system. This 20MB range at the very top of addressable memory space is lost to APIC and Intel TXT.
>
> According to the above equation, TOLUD is originally calculated to: 4GB = 1_​0000_​0000h
>
> The system memory requirements are: 4GB (max addressable space) - 1GB PCI space) - 35MB (lost memory) = 3GB - 35MB (minimum granularity) = 0_​ECB0_​0000h
>
> Since 0_​ECB0_​0000h (PCI and other system requirements) is less than 1_​0000_​0000h, TOLUD should be programmed to ECBh.

I cannot understand how the calculation gives the figure 0_ECB0_0000. 3GB - 35MB is 0_BDD0_0000. Can anyone explain how Intel's figure is derived?

I have tried combining the numbers in the example in various ways, but cannot find anything that matches up with Intel's calculation. The example appears in the data sheets for a number of processors over a long period of time, suggesting it is unlikely to be an error.

Comment: Intel is not new to writing blatantly wrong statements in its manuals. In fact, the TOLUD is **above** the TSEG, the GTT Stolen Memory, and the Graphic Stolen Data. Quoting: "*The Top of Low Usable DRAM is the lowest address above both Graphics Stolen
memory and Tseg. BIOS determines the base of Graphics Stolen Memory by
subtracting the Graphics Stolen Memory Size from TOLUD and further decrements by
Tseg size to determine base of Tseg.*". So, if anything, the calculation should go like 4GiB - 1GiB (- 20MiB if you would also include the TXT and APIC regions). The C1DRB3 seems to be ...

Comment: ... related to the hold i915 NB, so I think that's a mistake on Intel's side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Good catch about the C1DRB3. I was wondering why I couldn't find a reference to that register anywhere else in the document. That does suggest the information might simply be wrong.